# jQuery image zoom foreground

Tags: jquery, image

I have a  tag with a bunch of image thumbnails, which are each placed in their own  tag.

```
<div class='imageframe'>
    <div class='imagecontainer'>
        <img class='clipartimage' src='myimageurl>
    </div>
    <div class='imagecontainer'>
        <img class='clipartimage' src='myimageurl2>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JQuery code so far:

```
$(".imagecontainer").click(function (event) {
    $(event.target).width(100);
    $(event.target).height(100);
});
```

What i would like to do, is show a larger version of the image, when the user clicks or hovers over the image. 
What i have so far, is i am able to double width and height of an image when it is clicked, but this just makes the image "spill over" into it's neighbouring pictures, and lie partially behind these. This is made worse by the fact that the pictures backgrounds are transparent.

What i need, is to have the picture move to the foreground when it is clicked(or hovered), and remove the transparency of it's background.

Unless it is a really big job to do something like this, i would prefer to write my own code for it.

Thanks

Comment: check this link http://www.walkswithme.net/tag/image-zoom-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok there has been several changes, but tell me if this is along the lines of what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/GqwbY/

```
var $target;
var targetWidth;
var targetHeight;
var targetPos;
var isAnimated;
$(".imagecontainer").hover(function(){
    $target = $('.clipartimage', this);
    if(!isAnimated){        
        targetPos = $target.position();
        targetWidth = $target.width();
        targetHeight = $target.height();
        isAnimated = true;
    }
    $target.stop().animate({'height':'200px', 'width':'200px', 'left': '-=' + (targetWidth / 2), 'top': '-=' + (targetHeight / 2) }, 200).css({
        'background': '#fff',
        'border':'solid 1px #000',
        'border-radius': '5px',
        'box-shadow': '0px 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.8)',
        'z-index': '2'
    });
}, function(){
    $target.stop().animate({'height':targetWidth, 'width':targetHeight, 'left': targetPos.left, 'top': targetPos.top }, 200, function(){ isAnimated = false; }).css({
        'background': 'transparent',
        'border':'solid 0px #000',
        'border-radius': '0px',
        'box-shadow': '0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.8)',
        'z-index': '1'
    });
});
```

I think it actually looks a little nicer without the border/bg, but its up to you. Hope this helps!

Edit: Tried to make it as dynamic as possible. You can obviously change out the styles however you need. Hopefully this works for you. Good luck!

Comment: Unless doing something like this is a really big job, i would prefer to do it with my own code.

Comment: That is completely understandable, I will mess around in fiddle for a few and see wha comes up.

Comment: I'm still playing with it as well, so I will continue to update as it gets better.

Comment: I got this to work. Had to change it a bit, since the images didn't necessarily fit perfectly into the div tags. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the z-index to 1000 when hover or for a time you like

```
$(event.target).css("z-index","1000");
```

guess this would look like this if im minded right :)

```
$(".clipartimage").on('click',function () {
    $(this).width(100);
    $(this).height(100);
    $(this).css("z-index","1000");
});
```

i made a hover function for you with keeping the old image sizes

```
// Vars to get old size back
var oldH = 0;
var oldW = 0;
$(".imagecontainer").hover(function () {
    // Function for Hover Element
    oldH = $('.clipartimage',this).height();
    oldW = $('.clipartimage',this).width();
    $('.clipartimage',this).width(300);
    $('.clipartimage',this).height(200);
    $('.clipartimage',this).css( 'z-index', 1000 );

}, function(){
    // Function for hover out
    $('.clipartimage',this).width(oldW);
    $('.clipartimage',this).height(oldH);
    $('.clipartimage',this).css( 'z-index', 0 );
});
```

here is a demo **[http://jsfiddle.net/rfCkD/](http://jsfiddle.net/rfCkD/1/)**

**SLIM VERSION WOULD BE LIKE**

```
// Vars to get old size back
var oldH = 0;
var oldW = 0;
$(".imagecontainer").hover(function () {
    // Function for Hover Element
    oldH = $('.clipartimage',this).height();
    oldW = $('.clipartimage',this).width();
    $('.clipartimage',this).width(300).height(200).css( 'z-index', 1000 );
}, function(){
    // Function for hover out
    $('.clipartimage',this).width(oldW).height(oldH).css( 'z-index', 0 );
});
```

**IMPORTANT:**
in your case you sayed that your imagecontainer has:

```
.imagecontainer
{
    float:left;
}
```

so if you want your images to listen to z-index, your images **need**:

```
.clipartimage
{
    position:relative;
}
```

you could also use position:relative on your container...
i hope that's what you were looking for :) otherwise you may look for animation if you want images to make space for view.

Comment: .imagecontainer has float:left; and i am guessing that is why z-index doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: could you post your css to ? i think the solution is easy but i need more code to see whats your behavior :)

Comment: so i have the solution for your problem :)
i will update my post

Comment: i tried  wrxsti's post on fiddle. seems a little buggy to me.... if i hover the images on bottom line and moving mouse from left to right and on each move a lil bit up the images move up to until they leave my screen :)

Comment: Interesting...What browser are you using? I was unable to recreate, but I could certainly see something like that happening. I'll definitely fix it if I can recreate it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will look closer at this on monday when i get to work.